# Multiple content div loading with ajax/json

Tags: json, jquery

I have implemented external content loading using Ajax. And now I would like to add multiple container loading functionality using a Json object code I have.

Could you please help me incorporate the json object code into the Ajax code. My knowledge in coding is very limited :)

Here is the detailed info:

Here is the json object:

```
var json = [{
  'id': 'content',
  'wrapper': '__content-wrapper'
}, {
  'id': 'content',
  'wrapper': '__content-wrapper'
}]

$.each(json, function(i, itm) {
  $('#' + itm.id).wrap('<div id="' + itm.wrapper + '"></div>');
  pageload(itm.id, itm.wrapper);
}

function pageload(id, wrapper) {

}
```

Here is the Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var contentWrapID = '___content-wrapper';

  $('#content').wrap('<div id="' + contentWrapID + '"></div>');

  function showNewContent() {
    $("#" + contentWrapID).slideDown();
    $('#load').fadeOut();
  }

  function pageload(hash) {
    if (hash) {
      $("#" + contentWrapID).load(hash + " #content", '', function() {
        if ($('img:last', this).get(0)) {
          $('img:last', this).load(function() {
            showNewContent();
          });
        } else {
          showNewContent();
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#" + contentWrapID).load("index.html #content");
    }
  }
  $.historyInit(pageload);

  $('#topnav li a').click(function() {

    var hash = $(this).attr('href');
    hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
    $("#" + contentWrapID).slideUp(300, function() {
      $.historyLoad(hash);
    });
    if (!$('#load').get(0)) {
      $('#container').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    }
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    $('#topnav li a').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    return false;
  });
});
```

........................

As far as I understand I have  to replace this line:

`var contentWrapID = '___content-wrapper';`

with the json object:

`var json = [{'id': 'content', 'wrapper': '__content-wrapper'},{'id': 'content2', 'wrapper': '__content-wrapper2'}];`

But I also have to change the pageload function so that it works with the new variables that are passed:

```
function pageload (id, wrapper) {

}
```

I'd also like to add that this is what I'm trying to accomplish in particular:

1. To be able to load content into, (lets call it #div 1) extracted from a corresponding #div in a html page, (lets call it featured.html) with a click on any of the tabs in the 1st navigation menu, (lets call it #topnav).
2. To be able to load content into, (lets call it #div 2) extracted from a corresponding #div in another html page, (lets call it news.html) with a click on any of the tabs in the second navigation menu, (lets call it #vertnav-bar).

P.S Only one div gets loaded for every click. (From what you explained I think this particular detail is important that i mention with regards to the pageload calling function. In other words at no one given point in time will a click be loading data to more than one #div

I'd be very grateful for any help

Best regards
Paul

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need something that will take the JSON data taht you have loaded via Ajax calls and put this JSON object into the some HTML. Maybe you should take a loom at the http://code.google.com/p/jquery-load-json/ JQuery plugin. It enables you to load json object into the any html element

```
$("#div1").loadJSON( jsonObject );
```

Where 'div1' is id of your element and jsonObject is the JSON object you have already loaded. there are few examples on the plugin site that can help you as example http://jquery-load-json.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/categories-ajax.html where it is shown how you can take json object with categories and load them into the drop-down list. Each time parent category changes, child will be reloaded. It looks like simplified case of your example.

Jovan